# IBM Bluemix erroring when creating volumes via docker-compose up

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I am currently trying to get a docker-compose.yml working with Bluemix. The docker-compose.yml works fine when used directly with docker. Here the error message:

> $ docker-compose -f docker-compose-bluemix.yml up -d
>   Creating volume "angularexpress_iib-binary" with default driver
>   Creating angularexpress_iib-binary_1
>   ERROR: "angularexpress_iib-binary"

I have created the volumes manually to see if it would help, but still getting the same error message:

> $ cf ic volume list
>   iib
>   iib-binary

The relevant sections in the docker-compose-bluemix.yml are as follows:

```
 version: '2'
 services:
 iib:
 iib-binary:
    image: ${BLUEMIX_REG}iib-binary:v10.0.0.4
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    volumes:
     - iib-binary:/iibBinary
 volumes:
    iib-binary: {}
```

Just to provide some more context.

- I have already loaded all the dependant images to Bluemix
- I have created a new version of the original docker-compose.yml file to ensure all dependant images are pulled from the Bluemix registry
- bx version 0.3.1-7b45723-2016-03-16T02:55:28+00:00
- cf ic (Docker) version 1.10.3-cs2, build f02424d
- cf version 6.16.1+924508c-2016-02-26

Any help or pointers to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated!

Thanks, Patrick

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved the issue by making the docker-compose file v1 compatible. Bluemix does not yet support docker-compose v2.

Here the fixed yml:

```
 iib:
 iib-binary:
    image: ${BLUEMIX_REG}iib-binary:v10.0.0.4
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    volumes:
     - /iibBinary
}
```

What changed?

- Removed line ==> version: '2'
- Removed line ==> services:
- Changed " - iib-binary:/iibBinary" to " - /iibBinary"
- Removed complete "volumes:" section at the bottom

I hope it helps someone.
Regards, Patrick

Comment: Yes, this line in the Bluemix documentation is misleading - "Install or upgrade to the latest version of the Docker Compose software package on your computer." source: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_compose_intro.html#container_compose_ov