# Docker Compose in Bluemix KeyError Message

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I get an error when deploying 2 services in Bluemix using docker-compose:

```
Creating xxx

ERROR: for xxx-service 'message'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 116, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 876, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 416, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 66, in parallel_execute
KeyError: 'message'
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

My docker-compose file (that perfectly runs in local) is:

```
yyy-service:
    image: yyy
    container_name: wp-docker
    hostname: wp-docker 
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: whatever
    volumes:
      - "~/whatever/:/var/www/html/wp-content"
    links:
         - xxx-service

xxx-service:
    image: xxx
    container_name: wp-mysql
    hostname: wp-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: whatever
      MYSQL_DATABASE: whatever
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: whatever
    volumes:
        - /var/data/whatever:/var/lib/mysql
```

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222133/inconsistent-issue-when-using-docker-compose-in-bluemix), but I see no solution, except for trying

```
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=300
```

which hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, docker-compose eats the actual error messages returned and gives you a helpful stack trace of their python script with no info about the underlying cause.

From your compose file, my guess is that the issue is with your volumes.  You've specced it to mount directories on your compute host directly into your containers.  That won't work in Bluemix - instead you need to specify that the volumes are external (and create those first), then point to them.

For example, something like:

```
version: '2'

services:
    test:
      image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty
      volumes:
        - test:/tmp/data:rw

volumes:
  test:
    external: true
```

where you create the volume (in this case, "test") first with something like `cf ic volume create test`

Comment: Thanks @N Fritze, you were right; the problem was with volumes. I had to modify your solution because Bluemix currently does not support version '2' of docker-compose. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645126/ibm-bluemix-erroring-when-creating-volumes-via-docker-compose-up